# Match string to a filename from folder using php

Tags: php, file

Hi I wonder if it is possible to match a string to a file from folder using php.

For example  I have a folder called **uploads** and inside, I have different files like *image1.png*, *image2.jpg*, *doc1.doc*, and *doc2.pdf*.

Assuming I have this code on my php file:

```
<?php
 $string = "image2";

 // I need some function to display the image2 on my webpage.
 // If string "image2" is found in the uploads folder
 // then it should display the image 

?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this one should do what you want

```
$dir = "uploads";//the path to your folder
if(file_exists($dir)){
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
              while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                  if (!is_dir($file)) {

                    if ($file == "image2"){
                        // your code
                    }
                }
              }
           }
        }
```